# Compressed row - CSS

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have this main container div with multiple div inside. i want to display it with two columns. but the problem is the first column has space and it is aligned into the second div in the second column. I only want to have two columns and don't aligned with each other.

Here's the code, view it in `full-page`

```css
.mainContent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='mainContent'>
  <div class='content' style="height:200px"></div>
  <div class='content' style="height:500px"></div>
  <div class='content' style="height:100px"></div>
  <div class='content' style="height:700px"></div>
  <div class='content' style="height:500px"></div>
  <div class='content' style="height:300px"></div>
</div>
```

[image: unwanted space]

Answer (score -1):

This is because, `gap: 15px` and `width : 49%`.
It the browser width is wide enough, then the gap is implemented and contents aligned in 2 columns, but if not, it is just what you said.

So, please fix like this.

```css
.mainContent{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  row-gap: 15px; //=> it is important
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: space-between;
}

.content{
  background: green;
  width: 49%;
}
```